# Scan directory with PHP and use results in JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, scandir

I scan a directory with PHP which includes only folders:

```
$folders = scandir('gallery');
```

Now i want to check if a string in javascript a folder in this directory.

```
if(theString == allTheFolders){
     alert('yay');
}
```

Now `$folders` is an array with strings in it. To get all the strings i use a foreach loop and ignore the `'.' & '..'` directory's. But how can i get all these folders in the if loop?
Hope you understand my question!

Comment: you can't compare a string with a PHP-Array! you can only compare the string with one folder!

Comment: @Karen: Uhm, yes i know. so this is my Question! 'allTheFolders' stays for compare the string with all found folders...

Comment: JS is visible to the client, so I don't know if security means a great del to you, but displaying your complete folder structure to possible attackers doesn't seem like a good idea to me...

Comment: @11684: `gallery`'s folder structure might not be security-essential ;)

Comment: @11684: I create with uploads new folders. So i don't want for every new album edit my javascript. So i want to scan only the gallery folder to get all albums :)

Comment: Okay, just wanted to make sure you realized the possible threat!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Echo out your array as JSON, right into your JavaScript.

```
echo 'var folders = ', json_encode($folders);
```

Then you can loop through or do whatever you need directly in JavaScript.

---

**Edit:** Now that you have posted your actual question...  Do this in your JavaScript:

```
var wantedFolder = 'something';
var wantedFolderFound = false;
for (folderIndex in folders) {
    if (folders[folderIndex] === wantedFolder) {
        wantedFolderFound = true;
    }
}
if (wantedFolderFound) {
    alert('Folder found!');
} else {
    alert('Folder not found.');
}
```

As an alternative, I would probably use `Array.indexOf()`.  It isn't available in all browsers, but that problem is easily remedied.  See the documentation:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

Comment: Brilliant, I had the `json_encode`, but didn't know how to get it to the JS! +1

Comment: Okay. I think, var folders is now a array... Uhm. how can i now insert all the folders in my if loop? :S

Comment: @dTDesign, Your question makes no sense.  Are you trying to loop through all folders?  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Comment: When i see it correct, i get now a array of all folders. Now my target is to check, if my string is a album. So i must compare it with all the results in the folders-array. But i don't know how i should do that...

Comment: Oh ok, i think it isn't a array. I try it with google... +1 for your help, thank you